# How to create index for a query which does sorting on some fields?

Tags: mongodb

We are using Mongodb for our Application 
I have got a query regarding creation of indexes on a collection .

First of all below is my query which will do a find on DB and returns the data

```
db.mycollection.find({ symbol: "UGHNG", date: "2013-11-08", mainsymbol: "HIJ" }).sort( { "price": 1,"surv": 1} ).pretty()
```

As you can see from the above query that there are two fields price and surv which are used for **sorting** purpose only .

What is the best way for creating index for the above

Create a compound Index which includes every field of the above query .

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({"symbol":1,"date":1,"mainsymbol":1,"price":1,"surv":1},{"unique" : false})
```

OR

Create 2 single indexes and one compund index  as shown below to serve the above query

```
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({"price" : 1}, {"unique" : false})
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({"surv" : 1}, {"unique" : true})
db.mycollection.ensureIndex({"symbol":1,"date":1,"mainsymbol":1},{"unique" : false})
```

Please share your views as what is the best approach in terms of handling this in all aspects (RAM Size , query performance )

Comment: It is still only one index per query until https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3071 so I don't see the point of the second option

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have queries that need use only one of `price` and `surv`, I think the compound index should do the best work.

Comment: hey Anudeep , I didn't understand what do you mean by this "Unless you have queries that need use only one of price and surv" ??

Answer (score 0):

the best approach is to use .explain()

this will let you know how much work is done with each version of your index

it is really worth the time to explore the explain method and learn to interpret its output.